# Why can I not authenticate my application? Application is not allowed to request implicit grants

Tags: support, discussion

I created a placeholder. [PLACEHOLDER - Disco Application](https://stackapps.com/questions/8794/disco-application#8794) I created an application and added placeholder. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=19204&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success but I received:

> Application is not allowed to request implicit grants

Answer (score 1):

Hooray! I fixed it. I forgot to check "Enable Client Side OAuth Flow". Now it works.